# nodejs - Share session between express and socket.io (authentication with passport)

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, passport.js

I am currently creating a webapplication using node.js.
When a user enters the side, a connection via socket.io is built up.
I want to block multiple connections. A user should just be able to connect one time, if he opens the page in another window, i want to display a message like "already connected, please close all other tabs", or something like that.

To do so, i create sessions for the users using "express-session". this sessions are shared with socket.io by using following code.
I am not sure, if i am doing it correctly. I have looked at some tutorials and they are all sharing the sessions in a similar way. But sometimes, i think, the session data is overridden, when i change and save a value in the  socket.io-session.

```
var sessionStoreClient = Redis.createClient({
    port: DBs.sessionStore_redis.port,
    host: DBs.sessionStore_redis.host,
    password: DBs.sessionStore_redis.password,
    db: DBs.sessionStore_redis.database
});
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
    unset: "destroy",
    client: sessionStoreClient
});

var sessionInstance = expressSession(
    {
        key: sessionsKey,
        store: sessionStore,
        secret: sessionsSecret,
        unset: "destroy"
    }
);
app.use(sessionInstance);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

to share the sessions with socket.io, i am using following code

```
var passportSocketIo = function(app,sessionInstance, passport){
return function(socket, next){

    var req = socket.request;

    sessionInstance(req,req.res,
        function () {

            if (!req.session) {
                return next(new Error("Not authorized"), false);
            }

            req.updateSessionValue = function (propertyName, propertyValue, callback) {
                if(!req.session){
                    console.log("unauthorized session modification");
                    return;
                }
                req.session.reload(()=>{
                    req.session[propertyName] = propertyValue;
                    req.session.save();
                    if(callback)
                        callback(propertyName, propertyValue,req.session);
                });
            };

            if(req.session.passport && req.session.passport.user) {
                passport.deserializeUser(req.session.passport.user, req, function (err, user) {
                    req.user = user;
                    req.user.logged_in = true;
                    return next(null, true);
                });
            }else {
                return next(null, true);
            }
        }
    );
    };
};

    var nsp = io.of(Packages.NAMESPACES.LOBBY);
    nsp .use(options.sessionMiddleware);
```

to edit the values of the sessions, inside of the socket.io-listeners, i use the function, which is set to the request in the code above.

```
_onConnectionReceived(socket) {
   socket.request.updateSessionValue("isConnected",true);
}
```

and when the user disconnects from the socket:

```
_onDisconnect(socket) {
   socket.request.updateSessionValue("isConnected",false);
}
```

For login and authentication I am currently using passport.js.

When the user logs out, he is redirected to the samepage, but as "guest"-user. For loggin out, I am using following code:

```
router.get('/logout',function(req, res,next){
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy(
        function (err) {
            res.render('logout',{});
        }
    );
});
```

The problem there is, that after the session is destroyed and the user is redirected, the socket.io disconnect event is fired. Even after the reload inside of the "onDisconnected" event-listener, the session seems to exist, after the value is modified, the session seems to get recreated somehow. Also it feels like, that the session values are sometimes just overwritten - i have not exactly found out why.

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to share and modify the sessions? Is the "reload" function of the session really reloading its data from the sessionStore?

Another approach could be to just save the session/user ids in a hashset, and check if there is already a connection open (without saving it in the session it self), but i am curious, if my approach is correct, becaus i need the sharing and modifing of the sessions anyways.